# An Application in Normed Vector Space is Uniformly Continuous iff is Identically Null.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $E_1,E_2,...,E_n,F$ vectorial normed spaces, with $n\geq 2$. An application "n-linear" $f:E_1\times E_2\times\cdots\times E_n\to F$ is uniformly continuous if, and only if, is identically null.

My approach: If $f\neq 0$, then exists $u_1\in E_1, u_2\in E_2,\cdots u_n\in E_n$, such that $f(u_1,\cdots,u_n)=v$, then if $u_1\to \frac{u_1}{\vert v\vert}$, we have $\vert f(u_1,\cdots,u_n)\vert=1$, I think we should define a proper function,  but don't know which, because the multiplication $m(\lambda,x)=\lambda x$, is not uniformly continuous, unless $E=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f\neq 0$, so that $f(u_1,\dots ,u_n)=c\neq 0$ for some $(u_1,\dots ,u_n)$. Now consider the function $\phi:\mathbb R\to F$ defined by 
$$\phi(t):=f(tu_1,\dots ,tu_n)\,.$$
If $f$ were uniformly continuous then so would be $\phi$ be cause the map $t\mapsto (tu_1,\dots ,tu_n)$ is uniformly continuous. But $\phi$ is *not* uniformly continuous because $\phi(t)=t^n\, c$ and $n\geq 2$.

Comment: This uses that the composition of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Which is easy to prove.

Comment: True, even elementary, I just wanted to add it in (I didn't mean it as criticism). The proof runs as follows: If $(M_1, d_1), (M_2, d_2), (M_3, d_3)$ are metric spaces and $f: M_1 \to M_2$ and $g: M_2 \to M_3$ are uniformly continuous, and $\epsilon > 0$, we may choose $\mu > 0$ such that $d_2(a, b) < \mu$ implies $(d_3(g(a), g(b)) < \epsilon$ and then $\delta > 0$ such that $d_1(x, y) < \delta$ implies $d_2(f(x), f(y)) < \mu$. Then $d_1(x, y) < \delta \Rightarrow d_2(f(x), f(y)) < \mu \Rightarrow d_3(g(f(x)), g(f(y))) < \epsilon$.